# How do I Open A File Asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

What is the best way to execute file opening asynchronously even before copying begins. The exception I get is that the file is not accessible because its being used by another process.

```
try
{
    using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(pathToDownloadedMedia, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        using (var destinationStream = File.Create(pathToProcessedMedia))
        {
            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

I Tried an altenative as shown below but with no success. The same error prevails.

```
using (var sourceStream = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.Open(pathToDownloadedMedia, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)))
                    {
                        using (var destinationStream = File.Create(pathToProcessedMedia))
                        {
                            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: *"Execute file opening asynchronously"* The handle is being opened synchronously. Why do you think opening it asynchronously would make the error go away?

Comment: @Sharique Exiting using is disposing the file

Comment: You are opening FileStream with FileShare.None. Have you tried that with FileShare.Read?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I tried wrapping the File.Open() in a task and awaiting it but same error popped up

Comment: @DavidP I tried your solution and it still reports that the file is being used by another process!

Comment: This won't work, synchronously or asynchronously. It has nothing to do with that. You're simply accessing a file which is locked by another process.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov so what solution do you propose?

Answer (score 1):

No; different threads attempting to open the file at the same time will interfere with each other. You could lock a shared object to force the threads to run one at a time.

Or just use the built-in .NET tracing functionality; you can configure your app.config to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Simply switching to Fileshare.ReadWrite solved the problem

```
 using (var sourceStream = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.Open(pathToDownloadedMedia, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
                    {
                        using (var destinationStream = File.Create(pathToProcessedMedia))
                        {
                            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
                        }
                    }
```

I modified the solution by taking away the Task being created. It works well now.

```
 using (var sourceStream = File.Open(pathToDownloadedMedia, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (var destinationStream = File.Create(pathToProcessedMedia))
                        {
                            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This is not a proper use of Tasks, simply wrapping synchronous I/O code in a Task is a waste.